# Building layouts in Flutter like bootstrap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I build responsive layouts in Flutter like bootstrap or angular flex layout?

BootStrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Angular Flex Layout: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Answer (score 4):

Flutter has a different layout system from HTML.

There's no strict equivalent to this. Instead that feature is spread across the entire catalog of widgets.

Some of these widgets are:

- [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)/[Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) combined with [MainAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html) and [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html), for single line "flexbox"
- [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) for flexboxes that wraps
- [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) for regular grids
- [CustomMultiChildLayout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) for advanced grid templates
- [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) for layouts that depends on the size available (avoid `MediaQuery`)

Answer (score 0):

**2024 Update:**

You can try [Syncfusion Flutter Datagrid](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datagrid) as they give us so many options.

For more details about Syncfusion you can visit their [official website](https://www.syncfusion.com/)

[image]